# C++ - thread execution fails

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying run a function which will let the calling thread go to sleep for a given time. But when I run it i get the error `libc++abi.dylib: terminating. Abort trap: 6`

Sleep function:

```
void process_for(int cycles) {
    sleep(cycles);
}
```

And I defined the thread as below:

```
thread p1(process_for, 2000);
```

I also tried `this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000))` but that gave me the same error. What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to join your thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program compiles and runs successfuly

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void process_for(int cycles) 
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( cycles ) );
}

int main()
{
    std::thread p1( process_for, 2000 );

    p1.join();
}
```

It seems you forgot to join the thread.

Answer (score 1):

as the comment said.
you have to join the thread in the main

add

```
p1.join();
```

eventually see:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/